# GraphQL: sub-field per type vs root query field which can be filtered using args?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm working on a voting application, I have users, polls, and votes (middleman between users and polls).  I'm having troubles deciding what is the right thing to do in GraphQL, regarding accessing votes in my schema.

Should I have a `votes` field in my root query, containing all the votes, which can be filtered via args, for votes of a specific user, or on a specific poll?

Should I have a `votes` field under my root query - which resolves to all the votes, another one under each `user` - which resolves to all the user's votes, and another one under each `poll`- which resolves to all the poll's votes?

Are both ok?

I'm not asking which works but which is the right thing to do, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is the cleaner approach. It makes more sense to have Votes for each user queryable as a connection on the User type, and same with Polls. To get a single Vote, your `getVote` query  should accept a unique Vote ID as the query's argument, and if you want to retrieve all, I would suggest implementing pagination for a `getVotes` query that accepts standard arguments like limit, cursor, orderBy, first, or last.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is also the approach I'm taking right now, but it makes things difficult for me on relay mutations, any chance you could help me? Are you familiar with relay too?

Comment: No problem! And yes, what can I help you with?

Comment: It's about defining a fat query for this (somewhat complex) schema structure, I actually asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38192260/3137842. thanks!